# Wieso bedeutet "Kinderstube" Erziehung?

Tags: etymology

Dass *Kinderstube* gute Manieren oder Erziehung bedeutet, erfahre ich grad jetzt. Trotzdem war mein Versuch dessen Bedeutung nachzuvollziehen bisher erfolglos.

Einerseits ist *Stube* eine Räumlichkeit, ein Zimmer. Demzufolge klingt mir die Bedeutung von *Kinderstube* eher nach „Schule“. Wenn das total falsch ist, dann bitte die Etymologie des Wortes geben. Wenn aber etwas da dran ist,

- warum bedeutet *Kinderstube* „Erziehung“ und nicht „Ausbildung“?

Comment: *Stube* ist nicht irgendeine Räumlichkeit sondern bezog sich auf den beheizten Wohnraum. Dort wird man normalerweise nicht ausgebildet sondern erzogen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ich verweise mal auf Wikipedia: [Kinderstube](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinderstube)

> Der Begriff Kinderstube hat folgende Bedeutungen:
>
> - in der Biologie der Aufwuchsort von Arten im juvenilen Stadium
> - andere Bezeichnung von Kinderzimmer
> - die Bedingungen, unter denen jemand im Elternhaus erzogen wird, bzw. die guten Umgangsformen, die daraus resultieren
> - der Titel eines Liedzyklus von Modest Mussorgski, siehe Kinderstube (Liederzyklus)

Punkt drei ist der Punkt, der hier zutrifft.

Punkt zwei (Kinderzimmer) ist ein veralteter Begriff. Außerdem würde ich es auf ein (kleines) Kinderzimmer sehr kleiner Kinder eingrenzen. Wenn jemand sagen würde, ein Schulkind wohnt in der Kinderstube, fände ich das merkwürdig. Bei einem Kleinkind könnte ich mir das eher vorstellen.

Jedenfalls ist die Kinderstube im heimischen Bereich angesiedelt und ist damit mehr Erziehung, weniger Ausbildung. Kinderstube bekommt man im Elternhaus vermittelt, es wird nicht gelehrt.

Wenn man jetzt noch die biologische Definition kennt, dann wird deutlich, dass es eher frühkindliche Erziehung ist. Ein Kleinkind hat noch keinen Unterricht.

Answer (score 5):

Eine Stube ist ein kleines Zimmer. Eine Kinderstube ist also wörtlich genommen ein kleines Kinderzimmer. Mit Schule hat das nix zu tun. Im Kinderzimmer wird man groß. Da lernt man und wird erzogen. Und wenn das suboptimal läuft, dann wird auch das Ergebnis zu wünschen übrig lassen. 
Und hier wird dann auf die Manieren abstrahiert.

Comment: Solang man "seine gute Kinderstube nicht vergisst", ist doch alles kein Problem.

Comment: Au conträre... bei Tisch "Scheiße" sagen, und wissen, dass "Scheiße sagen" nicht schicklich ist, ist ein Problem... besonders für Frau von und zu ;)

Comment: *Oh Konträr....

Comment: Sind in alter Verwendung Stuben immer klein?

Comment: @CarstenSchultz... laut DWDS wohl nicht ausschließlich. Da wird auch Saal angeführt. Aber die Spekulationen über die Herkunft lassen mich vermuten, dass die Idee von klein doch irgendwie drin ist.

Answer (score 2):

Historisch betrachtet gab es die Kinderstube (samt hauseigenem Personal wie Kindermädchen und evtl. Hauslehrern) nur in bessergestellten Familien, in einfachen Familien lebten alle zusammen in einem oder wenigen Räumen.

Der Hinweis auf die Kinderstube ist eigentlich/ursprünglich ein Hinweis auf privilegierte Herkunft und die Erwartung, daß Menschen "mit guter Kinderstube" eine entsprechend "feinere" Erziehung und Ausbildung genossen haben.

Answer (score 0):

Die englische Wikipedia liefert noch einen interessanten Verweis: Es gab teilweise getrennte Schlaf- und Aufenthaltszimmer für Kinder, und im "Aufenthaltszimmer" wurde tagsüber gespielt, gegessen und vermutlich auch gelernt/erzogen. Da dieses wohl beheizt war, wäre für die deutsche Sprache – falls es hier auch so war – die "Kinderstube" als analoges Wort zu Stube für beheizten Aufenthaltsraum anzunehmen und die Gleichsetzung Kinderstube = Erziehung mithin nachvollziehbar, da dies nur in entsprechend hohen Kreisen anzunehmen ist.

Der Begriff der Stube ist seiner Herkunft nach keinesfalls als kleiner Raum anzusehen: Bei meinen Großeltern hieß der Wohnraum noch die "gute Stube" und vom Land her kenne ich das auch noch.